# java three lowest scores

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am having difficulty figuring out where I've gone wrong in this program.
It will give me the lowest score and the third lowest score, but not the second lowest score.

I am also at a loss for  how to make the program accept first name only or first and last name.
I know how to do one name or two, but not either or.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

(Find the three lowest scores)
Write a program that prompts the user to enter the number of students and each student’s name and score, and finally displays the student with the lowest score and the student with the second-lowest score and the student with the third lowest score.

Program must accept first name only or first and last name

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //variables
    String name1 = "";
    String name2 = "";
    String lowestName1 = "";
    String lowestName2 = "";
    String lowestName3 = "";
    double score = 0.0;
    double lowestScore1 = -1.0;
    double lowestScore2 = -1.0;
    double lowestScore3 = -1.0;
    int numStudent = 0;
    int i = 1;  //counter

    //get number of students
    System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
    numStudent = input.nextInt();

    for (i = 1; i <= numStudent; i++) {

        System.out.println("Student " + i + " of " + numStudent);

        System.out.print("Enter student's name: ");
        name1 = input.next();
        //name2 = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter student's score: ");
        score = input.nextDouble();

        if (i == 1) {
            lowestScore1 = score;
            lowestName1 = name1;
        }
        if (score < lowestScore1) {
            lowestScore1 = lowestScore2;
            lowestName1 = lowestName2;
            lowestScore1 = score;
            lowestName1 = name1;
        } else  {
            lowestScore2 = score;
            lowestName2 = name1;
        } 
        
        if (score > lowestScore1 && score < lowestScore2){
            lowestScore3 = lowestScore2;
            lowestScore2 = score;
        }
        
        if (score < lowestScore2) {
            lowestScore3 = lowestScore2;
            lowestName3 = lowestName2;
            lowestScore2 = score;
            lowestName2 = name1;

        } else  {
            lowestScore3 = score;
            lowestName3 = name1;

        } 
        
        
        

    }

    System.out.println("The lowest score was " + lowestScore1 + " and " + lowestName1 + " got it");
    System.out.println("The second lowest score was " + lowestScore2 + " and " + lowestName2 + " got it");
    System.out.println("The third lowest score was " + lowestScore3 + " and " + lowestName3 + " got it");
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry? I'm *obviously* new to this. But thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: easy : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/What_is_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work (I will explain everything below):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("First student name: ");
    String name1 = input.nextLine();
    boolean firstOnly = true;
    if(name1.indexOf(" ") != -1){
      firstOnly = false;
    }
    System.out.println("First student score: ");
    double score1 = input.nextDouble();
    
    System.out.println("Second student name: ");
    input.nextLine();
    String name2 = input.nextLine();
    
    if(firstOnly){
      while(name2.indexOf(" ") != -1){
        System.out.println("Please enter first name only");
        name2 = input.nextLine();
      }
    }
    else{
      while(name2.indexOf(" ") == -1){
        System.out.println("Please enter first and last name");
        name2 = input.nextLine();
      }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Second student score: ");
    double score2 = input.nextDouble();
    
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Third student name: ");
    String name3 = input.nextLine();
    
    if(firstOnly){
      while(name3.indexOf(" ") != -1){
        System.out.println("Please enter first name only");
        name3 = input.nextLine();
      }
    }
    else{
      while(name3.indexOf(" ") == -1){
        System.out.println("Please enter first and last name");
        name3 = input.nextLine();
      }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Third student score: ");
    double score3 = input.nextDouble();

    input.close();
    
    String[] names = {name1,name2,name3};
    double[] scores = {score1,score2,score3};

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      double min = scores[i];
      int minInd = i;
      for (int j = 1; j < 3; j++){
        if (scores[j] < min){
          min = scores[j];
          minInd = j;
        }
      }
      double tempScore = scores[minInd];
      scores[minInd] = scores[i];
      scores[i] = tempScore;

      String tempName = names[minInd];
      names[minInd] = names[i];
      names[i] = tempName;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      System.out.println(names[i] + ": " + scores[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Yeah..it is a lot.

OKAY SO the first part is just taking in user input: the names and scores. I also implemented the "either only first names or both first and last names only" feature.

The way I did that was to first take in user input for the first name. I created a boolean variable, `firstOnly`, that stores if the names should either be first names or not. If the value of `name1` contains a space, then we set this to false, otherwise it is true.

When we take user inputs for `name2` and `name3`, if `firstOnly` is true, then we will keep asking for user inputs until their input contains no space. If `firstOnly` is false, then we will keep asking for user inputs until their input contains a space.

Make sure that when you take in user input for the test scores, you type in `input.nextLine()` afterwards. This is because after you enter an `int` or `double` into user input, it will leave behind a trailing newline which will affect the following user input if it is a String.

Next, we store the 3 names and 3 scores in lists: `names`, `scores`. Now, we need to sort the lists with respect to `scores`. That is, we sort `scores` and shuffle `names` the same way so that the elements correspond to each other.

To sort `scores` we can use selection sort. I will quickly explain selection sort below:

Let's say we have an array, `arr` that has 4 elements. We find the minimum element from `arr[0]` to `arr[3]`. After we find this minimum element, we swap it with `arr[0]`.

Next, we continue to find the minimum element from `arr[1]` to `arr[3]` and swap it with `arr[1]`. We continue this process until we reach the end of our loops.

The key to this problem is to modify the "swapping" part of selection sort. By applying the same changes of `scores` to `names` the arrays elements will maintain the correspondence to each other prior to the sorting.

Here is a kind of "test" that may help demonstrate:

`names = {"Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Date"};`

`scores = {50, 20, 40, 60};`

We set our swapping element to `scores[0]`, `50` and find the minimum between `{50,20,40,60}`, which is `20`. We then switch `50` and `20`, and thus we switch `"Apple"` and `"Banana"`.

Now we have:

`names = {"Banana", "Apple", "Carrot", "Date"};`

`scores = {20, 50, 40, 60};`

We set our swapping element to `scores[1]`, `50` and find the minimum between `{50,40,60}`, which is `40`. We then switch `50` and `40`, and thus we switch `"Apple"` and `"Carrot"`.

`names = {"Banana", "Carrot", "Apple", "Date"};`

`scores = {20, 40, 50, 60};`

We set our swapping element to `scores[2]`, `50` and find the minimum between `{50,60}`, which is `50`. We then switch `50` and `50`, and thus we switch `"Apple"` and `"Apple"`, which has no change.

Thus, our final arrays are:

`names = {"Banana", "Carrot", "Apple", "Date"};`

`scores = {20, 40, 50, 60};`

Now we can print them out and they will be outputted from least to greatest (in our problem we can only have 3 names and 3 scores but it's the same idea).

I hope this helped answer your question! Please let me know if you need any further clarification or details :)

Answer (score 0):

Existing code has some logical flaws in the structure of `if-else` statements and the typos when reassigning the lowest score values.

The comparison should start from the minimal score and "shift up" previous scores: first the current score is compared to `lowestScore1`, then to `lowestScore2` and finally to `lowestScore3`:

```java
for (i = 1; i <= numStudent; i++) {
    System.out.println("Student " + i + " of " + numStudent);

    System.out.print("Enter student's name: ");
    name1 = input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter student's score: ");
    score = input.nextDouble();

    if (i == 1) {
        lowestScore1 = score;
        lowestName1 = name1;
    }
    if (score < lowestScore1) { // new minimum found
        lowestScore3 = lowestScore2;    // shifting up 2nd to 3rd
        lowestName3 = lowestName2;
        lowestScore2 = lowestScore1;    // shifting up previous min to 2nd
        lowestName2 = lowestName1;
        lowestScore1 = score;           // storing current minimum
        lowestName1 = name1;
    } else if (score < lowestScore2) {  // new 2nd minimum found
        lowestScore3 = lowestScore2;    // shifting up 2nd to 3rd
        lowestName3 = lowestName2;
        lowestScore2 = score;           // storing current 2nd minimum
        lowestName2 = name1;
    } else if (score < lowestScore3) {
        lowestScore3 = score;           // storing current 3rd minimum
        lowestName3 = name1;
    }    
}
```

However, this works fine only if *all the students have different scores*.

If the scores are repeated then several students may share the same score and therefore some collection of the students *per score* may be required.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution 1*

```
final class StudentReport 
{
 private static final class Student
 {
  private final String firstName,lastName;
  private final int score;
  
  private Student(BufferedReader console)throws Exception
  {
   System.out.println("Enter Your Name[FirstName.LastName]"); 
   
   //name split at the .[regex involves escaping the character with \\]
   String[] nameParts=console.readLine().split("\\.");  
   if(nameParts.length>2)//Whoo you have a wierd name
   {
    throw new Exception("You have wierd name1!!");
   }
   firstName=nameParts[0];   
   //last name available only if user typed a dot else make it empty
   lastName=nameParts.length==2?nameParts[1]:"";
   
   System.out.println("Enter Your Score");  
   score=Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
   
   //for neat output
   System.out.println("============================");
  } 

  //used to print the student in println method
  @Override
  public String toString() {
   return "Student{" + "firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", score=" + score + '}';
  }
 } 
 
 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
 {
  //I prefer this over scanner as scanner has many bugs with new lines and skipping inputs
  try(BufferedReader console=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)))
  {
   //This is where all the magic happens. All student's inserted into your queue are automatically sorted in ascending order of their marks[lowest to highest]
   PriorityQueue<Student> students=new PriorityQueue((Comparator<Student>)(s1,s2)->Integer.compare(s1.score,s2.score));
   
   //After this point all student's are  sorted in ascending order[lowest to highest] of their marks
   System.out.println("How many students you want to admit?");
   int numStudents=Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
   System.out.println("====================");
   for(int i=0;i<numStudents;i++){students.offer(new Student(console));}
   
   /*
    Now we just have to poll[remove] the first 3 elements which will give us the 
    Lowest , 2nd Lowest & 3rd Lowest Student
   */  
   System.out.println("Call your parents[Lowest Score]="+students.poll());
   System.out.println("Meet me after class[2nd Lowest Score]="+students.poll());
   System.out.println("You can do better[3rd Lowest score]="+students.poll());
  }
 }
}
```

Output

```
How many students you want to admit?
5
====================
Enter Your Name[FirstName.LastName]
John.Smith
Enter Your Score
100
============================
Enter Your Name[FirstName.LastName]
James.Douglus
Enter Your Score
80
============================
Enter Your Name[FirstName.LastName]
Jimmy
Enter Your Score
70
============================
Enter Your Name[FirstName.LastName]
Charlie
Enter Your Score
50
============================
Enter Your Name[FirstName.LastName]
Henry.The3rd
Enter Your Score
20
============================
Call your parents[Lowest Score]=Student{firstName=Henry, lastName=The3rd, score=20}
Meet me after class[2nd Lowest Score]=Student{firstName=Charlie, lastName=, score=50}
You can do better[3rd Lowest score]=Student{firstName=Jimmy, lastName=, score=70}
```

*Solution 2*

If your assignment does not allow you to use PriorityQueues then you can use this logic

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
 {
  //I prefer this over scanner as scanner has many bugs with new lines and skipping inputs
  try(BufferedReader console=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)))
  {  
   System.out.println("How many students you want to admit?"); 
   int numStudents=Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
   
   Student[] students=new Student[numStudents];
   for(int i=0;i<students.length;i++){students[i]=new Student(console);}
   System.out.println("====================");
   
   
   
   //Finding the 1st,2nd...nth lowest is simply a matter of finding the lowest then ignoring that element in successive iterations 
   
   //create an temporary array which will hold students which we have already assessed
   int[] toIgnore={-1,-1,-1};
   //since we want only 3 students we run our loop 3 times
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
    //holds the nth lowest student for this iteration
    int lowestStudent=-1;
    
    lowest : for(int j=0;j<students.length;j++)
    {
     //we check if the current student at jth index was already assessed as the lowest in the previous iteration
     for(int ignore:toIgnore)
     {
      //looks like we already dealt with this student so we continue on with others
      if(j==ignore)
      {
       continue lowest;
      } 
     }
     
     Student currentStudent=students[j];       
     if(lowestStudent==-1)
     {
      //very first assigment
      lowestStudent=j;
     }
     else if(currentStudent.score<students[lowestStudent].score) 
     {
      //we found our new lower student
      lowestStudent=j;
     } 
    }
    
    if(lowestStudent!=-1)//happens if the number of students is lesser than 3
    {
     //add to ignore list
     toIgnore[i]=lowestStudent;
     System.out.println((i+1)+" Lowest Student="+students[lowestStudent]);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Using `PriorityQueue` is generally fine but this is very likely a school assignment, so possibly it may not be allowed

Comment: @Alex Rudenko the user hasn't explicitly stated what are the terms and conditions of his assignment so for now this could be an option.  He did say "Any help would be appreciated"